# Error when trying to upgrade TypeScript

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

I wish to update my TypeScript to the latest version

First I did it globally and then I tried it locally, ie

```
D:\dev\myapp>npm install - typescript@latest 
D:\dev\myapp>npm install  typescript@latest --savedev
```

I have 2 similar projects (Ionic 2)

The first (almost blank test project) worked fine, but the second I get the following error..

```
 myapp@ D:\dev\myapp 
    `-- typescript@2.1.5  invalid
```

I look in package.json and it has not updated  (still 2.0.9)

I have tried it a couple of times, but keeps failing. I have no idea how to track this down.

Does anyone have have any ideas?

Thanks in advance!

[UDPATE]
Thought would add the extra warnings I get

```
    npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@^1.0.0 (node_modules\chokidar\node_modules\fsevents):
    npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.0.17: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current:
    {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
    npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/compiler@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
    npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/compiler-cli@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
    npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/core@^2.3.1 but none was installed.
    npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.4 requires a peer of @angular/tsc-wrapped@^0.5.0 but none was installed.
    npm WARN @ngtools/webpack@1.2.4 requires a peer of webpack@2.2.0 but none was installed.
    npm WARN @angular/core@2.4.4 requires a peer of rxjs@^5.0.1 but none was installed.
```

Answer (score 0):

Try updating npm and then try again, could do the trick.

Comment: Ok, I tried that, went from 4.0.3 to 4.1.2, but unfortunately didn't do the trick, exactly the same error.